# In which Stack Exchange community should I ask clarifications for the code written by another author?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have posted [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208967/set-timeout-in-angular-in-a-bit-complex-way?noredirect=1#comment403686_208967) on codereview.stackexchange.com. Someone made me realize that it is not the best place to ask that question as they **expect me, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is**. The same person gave me [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) to educate my self. Still, I cannot decide where should I ask a question like this. Please advice me.

Comment: I'm no Angular expert, but it almost looks as if you're asking a question that would best be answered by finding and reviewing the API for the library.

Comment: Not sure you should ask that question here.

Comment: Generally this question would be on topic here, ***but*** we'd expect you to ask a more detailed question about it. What did your research and understanding reveal that you *do* understand? What precisely *don't* you understand about it? Just giving us a piece of code and asking us to explain it could take ages, if we're starting at how the interpreter parses and compiles the code into executable byte code which–––CARRIER LOST

Comment: tl;dr: Showing your efforts usually makes us answering your question easier.

Comment: I would like to thank you all for the opinions. I made the question narrower and specific.

Comment: @KushanRandima That question (as currently posed) seems reasonable for stack overflow. I probably even know the answer :)

Comment: Also, before posting any code that doesn't belong to you, you need to make sure it is appropriately and compatibly licensed.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, the code is not restricted to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell.

Comment: Original question has already been asked and answered on Stack Overflow at least twice, see [What is setTimeout doing when set to 0 milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955650/what-is-settimeout-doing-when-set-to-0-milliseconds/33955673) and [`Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)